# c++ Passing a value the wrong way?

Tags: c++

When i am passing an object to a function, I am getting undesired results. It seems to happen when I pass a `Character` through a `Mage`'s action() function.

Here are some snippits of my code:

#### character.h

```
    class Character {
    public:
        Character();
        int getMaxLives() const;
        int getMaxCraft() const;

    protected:
        maxLives;
        maxCraft;
    };
```

#### character.cpp

```
    #include "character.h"

    Character::Character () {
        maxLives = 5;
        MaxCraft = 10;
    }

    int Character::getMaxLives() const {
        return maxLives;
    }

    int Character::getMaxCraft() const {
        return maxCraft;
    }
```

#### mage.h

```
    #include "character.h"

    class Mage {
    public:
        Mage();
        void action(Character c1);
    };
```

#### mage.cpp

```
    #include "mage.h"   

    Mage::Mage () { ... }
    void Mage::action(Character c1) {
        cout << "Max Craft: " << c1.getMaxCraft() << endl;
        cout << "Max Lives: " << c1.getMaxLives() << endl; 
    }
```

#### driver.cpp

```
    int main () {
        Character c1;
        Mage m1;

        m1.action(c1);
```

---

My ouput gives me the following:

Max Craft: 728798402 (The number varies)

Max Lives: 5

---

However, if in my diver, i do:

```
cout << "Max Craft: " << c1.getMaxCraft() << endl;
cout << "Max Lives: " << c1.getMaxLives() << endl;
```

I get:

Max Craft: 10

Max Lives: 5

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you meant for `MaxCraft = 10;` (in your default constructor) to actually be `maxCraft = 10;`. As @chris says in the comments, it appears that you're using some (evil, evil) C++ extension that allows implicitly-typed variables, so the `MaxCraft = 10;` line is simply defining a new variable named `MaxCraft`.

Comment: Judging by the data members, compiling with an extension for implicitly typed variables.

Comment: @chris Oh god, such extensions exist?

Comment: I've never heard of any myself, but it makes sense that it's compiling the way it would in (old, I think) C, where untyped variables default to `int`.

Comment: It's supposed to be maxCraft = 10; this is how I have it written in my code. It's just not letting me edit it...

Comment: @jsan Are you sure? It seems strange that the typo in your code would actually cause the problem you're having. Anyway, click the edit link harder.

Comment: It's telling me that there is code that is not formatted as code, therefore not letting me edit the post... If we assume that it's maxCraft = 10;, any ideas as to why its returning a huge number (that changes) and maxLives returns the constant number?

Comment: @jsan: *Never* retype code.  Copy and paste.  You might have made other transcription errors, and the code you actually have might not be the same as the code you *think* you have.

Comment: @jsan You're getting garbage values from `maxCraft` most likely because it's not being initialized. This would happen if you weren't assigning to it properly in the constuctor. Copy all of your relevant code into your question.

Comment: This seems to contradict the output of the two last statements, where c1 is accessed.

Comment: How do I paste many lines of code? I cant figure out how to get code formatting when pasting?

Comment: @jsan Put 4 spaces before each line.

Comment: Oddly enough, I imported the project form Dev-C++ to VS 2012 and it worked fine :|